# Does Ricci flow preserve symmetries?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, symmetry, ricci-flow

What does the following sentence mean: (see p.66 [The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry By Ben Andrews, Christopher Hopper](https://books.google.com/books?id=T_iLQ8w_N_0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false))

> The Ricci flow preserves any symmetries that are present in the initial metric.

What I understand is ${\rm Isom}(g_0)={\rm Isom}(g_t)$ $\forall t$. or ${\rm Isom}(g_0)\leq{\rm Isom}(g_t)$ $\forall t$.

> How to prove that? or any reference containing proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct interpretation is indeed that $\def\isom{\operatorname{Isom}}\isom(g_0)\subseteq \isom(g_t)$ for all $t,$ i.e. that if $\phi$ is an isometry of $g_0$ then it is an isometry of every $g_t.$ This is a simple consequence of the isometry-invariance of the Ricci tensor: since  $$\def\rc{\operatorname{Ric}}\rc_{\phi^*g} = \phi^* \rc_g$$ for any isometry $\phi$, the defining equation $\partial_t g_t = -2 \rc_{g_t}$ implies $$\partial_t (\phi^* g_t) = \phi^*(\partial_t g_t)=\phi^*(-2\rc_{g_t}) = -2\rc_{\phi^*g_t};$$ i.e. $\phi^* g_t$ is also a solution of the Ricci flow. Since $\phi$ is an isometry of $g_0$, these two Ricci flows have the same initial condition $\phi^*g_0 = g_0,$ so by uniqueness they must be equal for all time, i.e. $\phi^* g_t = g_t.$

Comment: Indeed we have $\def\isom{\operatorname{Isom}}\isom(g_0)=\isom(g_t)$ using backward uniqueness (which holds for example when $M$ is compact). See Theorem 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4920.pdf)

Comment: @ArcticChar: it is subset ($\supset$) and not equal $(=)$ on the quoted paper.

Comment: The other direction is proved by Anthony in this answer. @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: It is meaningless to me that one direction has been proved in paper and other direction here. they are two different questions and cannot be merged to deduce a corollary.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Your conclusion says that if we perturb a metric by RF its isometry group does not change.

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ compact? If yes then both uniqueness and backward uniqueness are applicable @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: That is not depend on compactness. and why we should apply both uniqueness and backward uniqueness? Perhaps I have misunderstood something here. What is the def of "backward RF"?

Comment: the backward uniquessness says that if $g_t$ and $h_t$ are two rf on the same $M$ and $g_T=h_T$ for some T, then $g_t = h_t $ for all $t<T$. It is still ricci flow. @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: Its name is misleading. Anyway, your conclusion is about comparing two set of family of metrics while mine is about a single family of metrics. And it is obvious here because: $g_t=g_t$.

Comment: To apply backward uniqueness we proceed as in Anthony's proof but backward: For any T positive, let $\phi$ be an isometry with respect to $g_T$. Let $h_t =\phi^* g_t$. Then they are both ricci flow and $g_T =h_T$. Then $g_0 =h _0= \phi^* g_0$ by backward uniqueness. Thus $\phi$ is also an isometry with respect to $g_0$. @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: Your argument seems to be true but I am confused. We can deform a ugly (without symmetry) sphere ($g_0$) to a round sphere (with high symmetry one) ($g_T$), but what your argument says is that $\def\isom{\operatorname{Isom}}\isom(g_0)=\isom(g_T)$!!

Comment: The main point is an ugly sphere cannot be deformed to the round sphere in finite time. @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: Do you know any reference about it or can you prove it?

Comment: I think in some special case it can be done. For example [see this applet by Anthony Carapetis](http://a.carapetis.com/csf/).

Comment: Exactly by backward uniqueness.... @C.F.G

Comment: @ArcticChar: It is hard to believe for me. But it seams you are right. So RF does not do anything in a finite time? All of its goodness is on limit time?

Comment: Useful discussion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, the extra symmetry can only be obtained in the limit (in Ricci flow and also many other cases, like curve shortening flow).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: But your applet make a curve rather round in finite time.

Comment: [See this follow-up post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808235/272127).